# How to reply to Outlook emails saved on your local drive?

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm a new user and new to C#.net and this is my first query. I have saved Outlook emails in at my local drive in a folder. The thing is I have to create a reply or reply to email with a new body. Below is the code which I have written till now. I couldn't do with CreateItemFromTemplate()

```
public void IterateMessages(string folderPath, string folderName, string emailName, string attachmentPath, string Subject, string mailDate, string To, string SenderName)
    {            try
        {                
            string uBank = string.Empty;
            string efolderPath = folderPath + "\\Emails\\";
            string tempSubject = string.Empty;
            string tempMailDate = string.Empty;
            string tempTo = string.Empty;
            string tempSenderName = string.Empty;
            string tempSName = string.Empty;

            string eBody = "  Hi,<br /><br /> Body here... <br /> <br /><br /><br /><br />";

            //Getting the Folder name from the Path given
            foreach (string frname in Directory.GetDirectories(efolderPath))
            {
                string[] vfolder = frname.Split('\\');
                uBank = vfolder.Last();  //getting foldername

                if (uBank == folderName)  //Comparing values for Validation
                {     
                   string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(frname + "\\", "*.msg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                    for(int i=0; i < Files.Length; i++)
                    {
                          Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

                          var item = app.Session.OpenSharedItem(Files[i]) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
                          item.Display();
                          item.Reply(); //Cant reply to the open email here. Some ambiguity..
                          item.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
                     }                        
               }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok so what problem do you have?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't describe why you came to us.  Okay, so you can't get it to work.  Are you getting errors?  If so, what are they?  How are you calling this code?  What is it actually doing?

Comment: I need to reply to the email saved on local drive. Is there any way through which i can reply to emails saved on drive. Bascially, im looping through the folders on my shared drive and doing validation so that i can fetch and reply to correct email. I can open and display the email using app.Session.OpenSharedItem() method but while item.Reply() is not opening the reply email. I need to pass all the parameters which i have mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: According to the documentation, `item.Reply()` returns a new `MailItem`.  You didn't say if you are getting any errors.

Comment: You may have to do this   `Outlook.MailItem newmail=mail.Reply(); newmail.Display();`

Answer (score 1):

`MailItem.Reply` returns the new (reply) message. You need to display that new message instead of the old one. Also, there is absolutely no reason to create a new instance of `Outlook.Application` in the loop - just do it once before you start looping through the files.